# how do i populate form fields using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
function populateForm(Id,data){
    function(result){
        $('#Id').html(result);
    }
}
```

btw , The above code sucks!

here 'data' is an array and consists of many columns and values.

1) how do i get only the value of the name column from the array and populate that into a specific input text box??

Comment: and i do not know the column names in the array.

Comment: Please can you update your question with the contents of the 'data' array?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what the `data` array looks like?

Comment: you need to use `$('').val(result)` to put data in a textbox

Answer (score 0):

use .val();

```
$("#field").val('yourval');
```